# Not able to install symfony on windows

Tags: php, windows, symfony, xampp

Hello I am trying to install symfony on Windows. I had follow the all require steps for it but it end up with below message.

> [RuntimeException]
>   Symfony can't be installed because the downloaded package is corrupted.
>   To solve this issue, try executing this command again:
>
> Symfony new demo 3.2.8

When i tried above command it says :

> 'symfony' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I have try to reinstall composer and Symfony package both but it does not resolve the issue. It stays the same issue again.

Please help me how can I install it on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You are required to make it run through PHP as its a script file.

This gets the installer (which it looks like you have already)

`php -r "readfile('https://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony`

Then `php symfony new demo 3.2.8` (asuming if php is in path otherwise you have to specify the php.exe path too)

For the full details see http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

Regards

Answer (score 1):

forget  about  that installer  use  composer from command line

`composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name`

BTW  i don't  know  what server you are using (wamp/xamp etc),  i recomending  this 
https://laragon.org/
it have composer and all  tools  that you need to start with symfony